# In ShellScript, how to call a function after completion of function which is already running?

Tags: shell-script, background-process

My script involves three shell functions. Two running in parallel. I have to call a third function when the two parallel running function completes it's execution. How to call that third function?

Syntax of my function:

```
startsetup1()
{
    ...
}

startsetup2()
{
    ...
}

report()
{
    ...
}

startsetup1 & startsetup2
report
```

Now, I have to call report function after `startsetup1 & startsetup2` this execution. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wait` command waits for the background processes to complete:

```
startsetup1 & startsetup2 & wait
report
```